# Does the type of y value affect the prediction power of model?

Tags: predictive-modeling, cnn, machine-learning-model

I am using the sunlight intensity time series data(X) to predict plant height(Y) in different locations using CNN model in Keras.

I am wondering if I change the group Y values into 2 categories: High and Low based on a threshold(so that the Y becomes dummy variable), will the model be less accurate in making predictions as compared to using the original numerical Y data? Thanks